# Scaling uv's isn't matching the image behind it

Tags: uv, transforms

I have a mesh which is perfectly straight and 32 units long and subdivided 64 times.

[image]
[image]

I am trying to scale my uv's in the uv editor so that each subdivision along this mesh is the full texture.

So I unwrapped fine and then tried to scale the island vertically by doing:

S -> Y -> 64

But this causes the uv's to be slightly outside the image range which is confusing me.

You can see here for what I mean:

[image]

How do i correct for this, i am unsure on whats causing this slight offset for the Y axis.

Comment: It can be caused by various reason. May be your UV's were not perfectly aligned in the first place but the offset was too small to be noticed, however, after scaling it 64 times.. Anyway, it should be easy to fix, just change the pivot to 3D cursor and scale it slightly down on Y axis until it aligns.

Comment: I was scaling from the pivot but it still goes too far. I must be missing something here.

Comment: If it goes too far you just scale it back down until it aligns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select your mesh in Object Mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> select apply Rotation & Scale.
2. Enter Edit Mode select all vertex <kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Unwarp <kbd>U</kbd>
4. After unwarp you will see dialog box at bottom left of screen. Make sure you checked Correct Aspect. Blend will auto scale UVMap to fit your image.
5. Carefully Adjust Margin at bottom of dialog, it will keep margin between other object UVmap so it will not collapse when you paint texture.

[image]

Comment: Hi this didn't seem to make any difference for me.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file?

Comment: I have since figured it out. It was an issue with the scale units i had.